# Using js functions for multiple buttons

Tags: javascript

I have audio recorder button that records audio through browser onclick using the following code:

```
const button = document.querySelector('button');
    const recorder = new MicRecorder({
      bitRate: 128
    });

    button.addEventListener('click', startRecording);

    function startRecording() {
      recorder.start().then(() => {
        button.textContent = 'Stop recording';
        button.classList.toggle('btn-danger');
        button.removeEventListener('click', startRecording);
        button.addEventListener('click', stopRecording);
      }).catch((e) => {
        console.error(e);
      });
    }

    function stopRecording() {
      recorder.stop().getMp3().then(([buffer, blob]) => {
        console.log(buffer, blob);
        const file = new File(buffer, 'music.mp3', {
          type: blob.type,
          lastModified: Date.now()
        });

        const li = document.createElement('li');
        const player = new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(file));
        player.controls = true;
        li.appendChild(player);
        document.querySelector('#playlist').appendChild(li);

        button.textContent = 'Start recording';
        button.classList.toggle('btn-danger');
        button.removeEventListener('click', stopRecording);
        button.addEventListener('click', startRecording);
      }).catch((e) => {
        console.error(e);
      });
    }
```

I have used and the first button is running as expected here: https://jsfiddle.net/6f5h38zL/2/
Now my question is how to apply the same logic for remaining buttons without writing code for each?

Comment: Use `const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button")` instead. Now you have a list of `button` nodes. Do a `buttons.forEach()` and add the event listener to all the buttons

Comment: Why don't you use a loop?

Comment: @GabrielLupu, thanks I followed your approach here: https://jsfiddle.net/6f5h38zL/6/ but did not work...any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all the buttons and operate on all of them. It looks like you're using Bootstrap though, which requires jQuery, and jQuery makes it a lot simpler to do this without explicitly looping over each button.

Here's an example with "vanilla" JS.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const recorder = new MicRecorder({
  bitRate: 128
});

buttons.foreach(button => button.addEventListener('click', startRecording));

function startRecording() {
  recorder.start().then(() => {
    buttons.forEach(button => {
      button.textContent = 'Stop recording';
      button.classList.toggle('btn-danger');
      button.removeEventListener('click', startRecording);
      button.addEventListener('click', stopRecording);
    });
  }).catch((e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });
}

function stopRecording() {
  recorder.stop().getMp3().then(([buffer, blob]) => {
    console.log(buffer, blob);
    const file = new File(buffer, 'music.mp3', {
      type: blob.type,
      lastModified: Date.now()
    });

    const li = document.createElement('li');
    const player = new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(file));
    player.controls = true;
    li.appendChild(player);
    document.querySelector('#playlist').appendChild(li);
    buttons.forEach(button => {
      button.textContent = 'Start recording';
      button.classList.toggle('btn-danger');
      button.removeEventListener('click', stopRecording);
      button.addEventListener('click', startRecording);
    });
  }).catch((e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="container text-center">
  <h1>Mic Recorder to Mp3 Example</h1>
  <p>Check your web developer tool console.</p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Start recording</button>
  <ul id="playlist"></ul>
</div>

<div class="container text-center">
  <h1>Mic Recorder to Mp3 Example</h1>
  <p>Check your web developer tool console.</p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Start recording</button>
  <ul id="playlist"></ul>
</div>

<div class="container text-center">
  <h1>Mic Recorder to Mp3 Example</h1>
  <p>Check your web developer tool console.</p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Start recording</button>
  <ul id="playlist"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But this does not work: https://jsfiddle.net/6f5h38zL/4/

Comment: I fixed this error immediately after I posted it. See the edit.

Comment: Still not working. Am I doing anything wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/xw6fzcje/

Comment: dude if you look at the error in the console you can clearly see whta the issue is. i typed `foreach` instead of `forEach`. i fixed the code in the answer, but do yourself a favor and try to debug yourself a little more. it will help you sharpen your skills.

Comment: Are you sure the issue is only with foreach? I dont think its working. Can you please edit on jsfiddle and show to get marked as an answer?

Comment: @shiva - it's never going to work anywhere without your MicRecorder class. You didn't provide that code so there is no way for me to give you a working example. Besides, downvoting me isn't going to make me wanna help you any more.

Comment: Thanks for that yes, defining the function resolved the error. now i am trying to solve handling playlist so that sits in appropriate divs